# Selecionar uma option com botão externo

Tags: html, html-select, html5-video, html-option

Boa tarde pessoal,

Eu preciso que, quando eu aperto em um botão, o mesmo faça com que uma específica 
`option` seja selecionada no `select`. Por exemplo, eu possuo 3 botões e 3 `options`:

```html
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>

<br><br>

<select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

> Se eu clicar no botão `1` irá selecionar a `option` `1`, se eu clicar no botão `2` irá selecionar a `option` `2`, e se eu clicar no botão `3` irá selecionar a `option` `3`.

Não sei muito de JavaScript, mas acho que provavelmente irei precisar usar.

Agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minha dica é colocar um ID em cada btn, e nos option vc coloca o value igual ao valor do ID, tipo o `btn1`, tem o `id=n1`, e o `option1` tem o `value=n1`, dessa forma vc diz que o value deve ser = ao id do elemento clicado, simples assim, veja

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
let btn = document.querySelectorAll('button');
let select = document.querySelector('select');

function troca(e) {
    select.value = e.currentTarget.id;
}

btn.forEach( (el) => {
    el.addEventListener('click', troca);
})
```

```html
<button id="n1">1</button>
<button id="n2">2</button>
<button id="n3">3</button>

<br><br>

<select>
    <option value="n1">1</option>
    <option value="n2">2</option>
    <option value="n3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Isso mesmo que eu precisava, obrigado!

Comment: @JeanFranz opa! Legal que resolveu ai :D valeu a força!

Comment: se for uma tag `a` muda alguma coisa ou é só alterar o `button` por `a`?

Comment: @JeanFranz muda sim, vc pode usar o href como referencia no lugar do id por exemplo, e coloca e.preventDefault na função pro link não interferir, ou então vc coloca o id no A e deixa o href=# mesmo, teoricamente vai funcionar normal